# Error When I run passenger-install-apache2-module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, passenger, centos6

I use Ruby 2.0.0, Rails 4 and Passenger. I could not sort out what my mistake is. When I try to run passenger-install-apache2-module I end up getting the error in the screenshot.

Please guide my step by step. I am using centos6 64 bit server.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That probably means that your server does not have enough memory to compile Passenger. Please temporarily add some swap space while running passenger-install-apache2-module.

Comment: my server is running on 256 mb ram will it not support the passenger-install-apache2-module ?

Comment: It does. You just need to add more swap space.

Comment: I have added 1024 of swap space but still shows the same error

Comment: Can you double check swap is installed. run "sudo swapon -s"